# removing extra blank spaces in python

Tags: python, string

I have a file which reads:

```
o hi! My name is Saurabh.




o I like python.
```

I want something like:

```
o hi! My name is Saurabh.

o I like python.
```

I tried the line:

```
removedSpaces=' '.join(lineWithSpaces.split())
```

Looks like it removes all the spaces

It gives me

```
o hi! My name is Saurabh.o I like python.
```

Which is incorrect. Is it possible to achieve the above output by anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
removedSpaces = re.sub(r'\n{3,}', "\n\n", lineWithSpaces)
```

This converts all runs of three and more newlines to two newlines.

Comment: It worked after playing around with number and \n. Thanks a lot.. --Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

```
'\n\n'.join(linesWithSpaces.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Not quite right; this replaces all spaces by two newlines. You want `split('\n')`.

Comment: @nneonneo, Santa: No. Not fixed. Now *every* newline in the string will be replaced by two newlines: `'\n\n'.join("a\n\nb".split("\n"))` gives `'a\n\n\n\nb'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while "\n\n" in lineWithSpaces:
    lineWithSpaces = lineWithSpaces.replace("\n\n", "\n")
```